# Labor law - Paid vacations

Tags: labor-law

I currently work in Portugal, and in this country, every full-time employee has 22 paid vacation days by law. The labor laws on this country also state that, of those 22 days, at least 10 of them must be consecutive work days (weekends, holidays, etc, don't count). Is it like this in other countries? Do other countries labor legislation also enforce employees to spend at least 10 consecutive work days of their paid vacations?

Comment: Do you mean that a worker is only eligible for 22 paid vacation days *if* at least ten of the days of vacation are taken consecutively?

Comment: No, each worker is eligible for 22 paid vacations and is mandatory that the worker spends 10 consecutive days (work days) of those 22 days (in that year).

Comment: Are you sure that you have to *take* two consecutive weeks or is it that your employer has to give you the chance to take two consecutive weeks if you want them? The second is the law in Germany.

Comment: Are you sure this is a country-wide law?  If so, can you provide a link to it, or an authoritative description?  I have seen mandatory consecutive vacation policies in certain industries and for certain personnel for specific reasons (usually to mitigate the risks of ongoing employee malfeasance).  But I can't imagine a reason for it to apply to *all* employees in country.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure that this is a nation-wide law, as much ridiculous as it sounds. Each worker must take at least 10 consecutive work days per year.

Comment: @YviDe are you saying that in Germany the worker has the freedom to spend his vacations days whenever they want and how they want, without any restrictions?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "free". Your employer has to give you the chance to take all days every year and to take at least 2 consecutive weeks if you want that (and all the people I know do that anyway). But you can't just decide "I'll take the next four weeks off", obviously.

Comment: @YviDe the employers by law must give the chance to their employees to spend all 22 vacation days on a year. What it is ridiculous is that the portuguese labor law forces an employee to spend at least 10 consecutive vacations days (work days, so excluding weekends, holidays, etc). Did I make myself clear?

Comment: I have never seen a *law* dictating this.  I have only seen company *policies* and industry *regulations*.  E.g., in the U.S. banking *industry* it is common (though I'm not sure if it's required by *regulation*), and the explanation given is that it prevents a single employee from cooking books, since when they have to leave for two weeks someone else *has* to take over their books and would catch any fraud.

Comment: @feetwet Thanks, that makes sense. I could post here a link to the portuguese code of labor laws but it is not translated... Anyway here it is (article 241, 8th paragraph): http://www.cite.gov.pt/pt/legis/CodTrab_LR1_005.html#L005S10 There you can see this "no mínimo, 10 dias úteis consecutivos. " which in english is: "at least 10 consecutive work days"

Answer (score -2):

[The law you cite](http://cite.gov.pt/pt/legis/CodTrab_LR1_005.html#L005S10) (Article 241.8) appears to be a requirement on the *employer* that the employee be *allowed* at least 10 consecutive work days *if desired*.

As mentioned in the comments to your question:

- There are employers who for various reasons implement mandatory vacation *policies* that require some vacation to be taken every year, and in some minimum consecutive unit.
- There are countries that require employers to give employees reasonable accommodations to take vacation, e.g., by requiring a consecutive period *if requested*.

It looks like that law is saying the latter, but it's possible your employer has added the former.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Portuguese law that supports the reading of "allowed" and "if desired."  It says that employer/employee agreements are subject to the requirement that at least 10 consecutive days be taken. There's no provision saying that the employee can waive that requirement. Your answer appears to be based on your opinion about what is normal in labor legislation, not in any knowledge of Portuguese law or labor regulations.

Comment: @phoog - Well the plain language of the law is right there for the reading.  I'm fluent in Spanish, not Portuguese, so if I'm missing some nuance I'll concede I could have lost it in translation.  But even at a high level it seems clear that Article 241 deals with guaranteeing workers a certain level of flexibility to enjoy their legally mandated vacation without excessive restriction by employers.  I don't see anything in that article that imposes a *requirement* on workers.

Comment: How about "desde que sejam gozados, no mínimo, 10 dias úteis consecutivos"?

Comment: @feetwet The policy of the 10 consecutive vacation days (work days) really is mandatory and is nation-wide, meaning that all employers (with no exception) must abide by it.

Comment: @phoog can you tell me what are the other countries those points stated on the answer are the normal regarding labor legislation?

Comment: @lalalalalala well it's just as feetwet says in must countries. Most countries don't make any requirement about consecutive days, and this that do, like Germany, put requirements on the employer that may be waived by the employee. But I say that based on my opinion about what is normal in labor legislation, not on any knowledge of any country's actual laws. ;-).

Comment: Feetwet: I suppose the inability of the employee to waive the requirement is supposed to prevent employers from putting pressure on their employees "off the books" to waive the requirement. Certainly in the US it is common to hear of managers or employers who frown on people who use all of their vacation days.

Comment: @phoog: My translation of that clause is that the employee "shall enjoy the use of at least 10 consecutive days."  And again, it's part of an Article that contains nothing but proscriptions on employers in the allocation of vacation time, and which indicates that violations of it are "administrative offenses."  (Granted, an exceptionally paternalistic government may decide that it's good for people to take vacation whether they like it or not, and it's an employer's job to ensure that they take it.  I'm just offering my plain reading of the law coupled with my general knowledge of labor law.)

Comment: @lalalalalala - ultimately these laws are implemented by a government bureau as rules or regulations.  Can you find that bureau and see if they have published anything more conclusive, perhaps including an explanation of the purpose of this law?  E.g., what is the penalty for the "minor administrative offense" of failing to provide for 10 consecutive days vacation?  Is it applied to the employer without exception, or can the employer avoid sanction by showing that it provided for the vacation in accordance with Article 241 but the employee chose not to use it?

Comment: It is a good idea to look at regulations implementing the law.  On the other side of it, it might be that the reason for the apparent global application of the law (as reported by @lalalalalala) is that a court has interpreted the law in that way (despite your very reasonable explanation for why the article *shouldn't* be interpreted like that).  So it might also be necessary to look at related court decisions.

Comment: How do you translate "interpolado" there?  I don't understand why that word is in the sentence.  But otherwise, the clause "desde que sejam gozados, no mínimo, 10 dias úteis consecutivos" seems to depend on the meaning of "gozados" -- does "'enjoy' vacation days" mean "enjoy the option of having" or does it mean actually enjoying a day without work.

Comment: @phoog - "Negotiated" or "arranged."  I would be quite amused if the meaning of that paragraph boils down to, "Enjoy your time off, or we'll fine you."  Presumably this law was written to protect blue-collar and trade workers.  If white-collar workers in Portugal are anything like those in the U.S., the only way to ensure they "enjoy a day without work" is to disable their smartphone and internet access ;)